# Unsubscribe LocationListener from LocationManager after getting location data

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, locationlistener

For some reason when I add removeUpdates() after the requestLocationUpdates() method, I don't obtain any location data at all. Am I not unsubscribing correctly?

```
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 1, mlocListener);
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 1, mlocListener);
mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);


public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
        {
            loc.getLatitude();
            loc.getLongitude();
            String text = "My current location is: " +
            "Latitude = " + loc.getLatitude() +
            "Longitude = " + loc.getLongitude();
            System.out.println("FINISHED:");
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
                    text,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a `Thread` inside my `LocationHandler` with a nested `while` which kept looping until a GPS location was found. When found I unsubscribed my `LocationListener`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make one method and do removeUpdates() in that. and call it from onLocationChanged() after you got your data.

Comment: You mean put the extra method in `myLocationListener` or the class which calls `myLocationListener`?

Comment: i mean in your activity or class. make one method and put mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener); in the method's body. Now after getting your location and data just call that method from there and its done :).

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036774/fetch-first-location-on-android-and-stop-updates/8036819#8036819) might help.

You unsubscribe *after* you got the location data, that means in the `onLocationChanged` method.

Comment: I understand what you mean but, I don't have access to the `removeUpdates()` method within the `onLocationChanged()` method

Comment: declare `mlocManager` as final, then you will be able to access it in `removeUpdates`.

Comment: I mean it's declared in a different class, and it'd be bad practise to make it public.

Comment: So find a way to get a reference to a context in the `onLocationChanged` method. That's the way to do what you need...